# Why IEnumerable<char>.ToString() doesn't work ?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, tostring

I wonder why can't we just convert IEnumerable to string using ToString() ! I mean what is the underlying reason behind this. 
Microsoft docs say " ToString() returns **A string** that represents the current object." What is this **A string** ? Is it a special property of the object ? Why int.ToString() works but IEnumerable.ToString() doesn't ?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. There are multiple things you could have done wrong, a [mcve] will helps us tell you which one it is.

Comment: It does work, It just doesn't give you the result you are expecting.

Comment: IEnumerable.ToString() works, like @HimBromBeere said. An IEnumerable can be a complexe object and if you want to display it you should loop it. That is the expected behavor.

Comment: What should `ToString()` return for an instance of `IEnumerable<Customer>`? Or `IEnumerable<DateTime>`?

Comment: Try `string result = string.Join(", ", MyEnumerable);` and alike

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: I think `var s = new String(MyEnumerable);` would work as well.

Comment: @Stefan No, but it will work if you use `MyEnumerable.ToArray()`

Comment: @Stefan: In *general case*, `new String(MyEnumerable)` doesn't do: e.g. `var MyEnumerable = new double[] {1.2, Math.PI, 4.56};`

Comment: @DavidG: ah, yes, my bad.

Comment: It is a reasonable question. The answer is that this would have to be a special case, and nobody ever thought it to be useful enough. So it is treated the same a s any other `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 2):

An `IEnumerable<char>` is not neccessarily a `string`. Imagine you have some service that returns an infinite number of characters (e.g. a stream). As there´s no end of that stream and data flows endlessly you are not able to call `ToString` and materialize a `string` from it.

However `ToString` just returns a representation of the *object*, not its *data*. In case of an array for instance, the **object** is the collection of items, or more general just a container. What you expect is the **data** that is *contained* in that container.

So when calling `myArray.Totring` for example you don´t get `{ 1, 2, 3 }`, but simply `System.int[]`. That´s what `ToString` returns if there is no override for the type: its type-name. The same happens in your case: there is no overrdie for `ToString` defined for `char[]` or `List<char>` or whatever, so the method falls back to use `typeofObject.FullName`.